# Dropwizard + SSL Configuration

Tags: dropwizard

Iam not able to configure Dropwizard using SSL..

Created a key/cert as follows:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl req -new -key server.key -days 365 -out server.crt -x509
keytool -import -file server.crt -keystore keystore.jks
```

and I had placed the generated keystore.jks along with my configuration file(yml)..
My configuration file has http entries as:

```
http:
 port: 8443
 connectorType: nonblocking+ssl
 ssl:
  keyStore: ./keystore.jks
  keyStorePassword: XXXXXX
```

Started the server..Facing an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
 at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1290) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1149) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
 at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: is this exception arise at the time of starting server or when a request is made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening when a request is sent.
Recreated keystore with the following steps and it's working fine.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name myservercert -in cert.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out keystore.p12

keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias myservercert
```

Comment: This is missing at least one step. What did you do to create your PEM files?

Answer (score 0):

In dropwizard configuration (yml file) add something similar to below.

```
connector:
    type: https
    port: 8443
    keyStorePath: /path/to/ssl/directory/keystore.jks
    keyStorePassword: changeme
    trustStorePath: /path/to/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    certAlias: selfsigned
```

Answer (score -2):

add to your config file (DW 0.7.1) and remove what you dont need:

```
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081
    - type: https
      port: 8444
      keyStorePath: config/unsecure.keystore
      keyStorePassword: password
      validateCerts: true
      headerCacheSize: 512 bytes
      outputBufferSize: 32KiB
      maxRequestHeaderSize: 8KiB
      maxResponseHeaderSize: 8KiB
      inputBufferSize: 8KiB
      idleTimeout: 30 seconds
      minBufferPoolSize: 64 bytes
      bufferPoolIncrement: 1KiB
      maxBufferPoolSize: 64KiB
      acceptorThreads: 1
      selectorThreads: 2
      acceptQueueSize: 8
      reuseAddress: true
      soLingerTime: 345s
      useServerHeader: true
      useDateHeader: true
      useForwardedHeaders: true
```